# Google Cloud Composer failed to connect to Cloud SQL PostgreSQL database

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-composer

I am creating a Google Cloud Composer to use Apache Airflow CloudSQLExecuteQueryOperator to sumbit a simple query to Cloud SQL PostgreSQL database. But it failed with the following error message:
psycopg2.OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly. This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.

Here is the complete Composer log:

> ### [2023-08-23, 22:01:46 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1091} INFO - Dependencies
> all met for dep_context=non-requeueable deps ti=<TaskInstance:
> from_gcs_to_cloudsql.delete_older_data_task
> manual__2023-08-23T21:53:59.693259+00:00 [queued]> [2023-08-23,
> 22:01:46 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1091} INFO - Dependencies all met for
> dep_context=requeueable deps ti=<TaskInstance:
> from_gcs_to_cloudsql.delete_older_data_task
> manual__2023-08-23T21:53:59.693259+00:00 [queued]> [2023-08-23,
> 22:01:46 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1289} INFO -
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- [2023-08-23, 22:01:46 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1290} INFO - Starting
> attempt 2 of 2 [2023-08-23, 22:01:46 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1291} INFO
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- [2023-08-23, 22:01:47 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1310} INFO - Executing
> <Task(CloudSQLExecuteQueryOperator): delete_older_data_task> on
> 2023-08-23 21:53:59.693259+00:00 [2023-08-23, 22:01:47 UTC]
> {standard_task_runner.py:55} INFO - Started process 9949 to run task
> [2023-08-23, 22:01:47 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:82} INFO -
> Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'from_gcs_to_cloudsql',
> 'delete_older_data_task', 'manual__2023-08-23T21:53:59.693259+00:00',
> '--job-id', '69591', '--raw', '--subdir',
> 'DAGS_FOLDER/from_gcs_to_cloudsql_v6.py', '--cfg-path',
> '/tmp/tmppozedbav'] [2023-08-23, 22:01:47 UTC]
> {standard_task_runner.py:83} INFO - Job 69591: Subtask
> delete_older_data_task [2023-08-23, 22:01:47 UTC]
> {task_command.py:393} INFO - Running <TaskInstance:
> from_gcs_to_cloudsql.delete_older_data_task
> manual__2023-08-23T21:53:59.693259+00:00 [running]> on host
> airflow-worker-cwhv4 [2023-08-23, 22:01:47 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1518}
> INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
> AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_EMAIL=my_email@test.com AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=airflow
> AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=from_gcs_to_cloudsql
> AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=delete_older_data_task
> AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2023-08-23T21:53:59.693259+00:00
> AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER=2
> AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2023-08-23T21:53:59.693259+00:00
> [2023-08-23, 22:01:47 UTC] {base.py:73} INFO - Using connection ID
> 'google_cloud_default' for task execution. [2023-08-23, 22:01:47 UTC]
> {base.py:73} INFO - Using connection ID 'proxy_postgres_tcp' for task
> execution. [2023-08-23, 22:01:47 UTC] {cloud_sql.py:948} INFO - DB
> connection URI
> postgresql://XXXXXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXX@127.0.0.1:44687/postgres
> [2023-08-23, 22:01:47 UTC] {cloud_sql.py:973} INFO - Creating
> connection a7ca1b7c-4200-11ee-9707-ae5f45f562f7 [2023-08-23, 22:01:47
> UTC] {warnings.py:109} WARNING -
> /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/cloud_sql.py:1003:
> AirflowProviderDeprecationWarning: The "schema" arg has been renamed
> to "database" as it contained the database name.Please use "database"
> to set the database name.   db_hook: PostgresHook | MySqlHook =
> PostgresHook(connection=connection, schema=self.database)
>
> [2023-08-23, 22:01:47 UTC] {cloud_sql.py:523} INFO - Downloading
> cloud_sql_proxy from
> https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 to
> /tmp/dqnjbnio_cloud_sql_proxy.tmp [2023-08-23, 22:01:49 UTC]
> {cloud_sql.py:540} INFO - Moving sql_proxy binary from
> /tmp/dqnjbnio_cloud_sql_proxy.tmp to /tmp/dqnjbnio_cloud_sql_proxy
> [2023-08-23, 22:01:49 UTC] {cloud_sql.py:610} INFO - Creating
> directory /tmp/dqnjbnio [2023-08-23, 22:01:49 UTC] {base.py:73} INFO -
> Using connection ID 'google_cloud_default' for task execution.
> [2023-08-23, 22:01:49 UTC] {cloud_sql.py:576} INFO - The credentials
> are not supplied by neither key_path nor keyfile_dict of the gcp
> connection google_cloud_default. Falling back to default activated
> account [2023-08-23, 22:01:49 UTC] {cloud_sql.py:613} INFO - Running
> the command: `/tmp/dqnjbnio_cloud_sql_proxy -dir /tmp/dqnjbnio -instances gcp_my_project_id:northamerica-northeast1:test=tcp:44687` [2023-08-23, 22:01:49 UTC] {cloud_sql.py:616} INFO - The pid of
> cloud_sql_proxy: 9951 [2023-08-23, 22:01:49 UTC] {cloud_sql.py:630}
> INFO - 2023/08/23 22:01:49 current FDs rlimit set to 1048576, wanted
> limit is 8500. Nothing to do here.
>
> [2023-08-23, 22:01:55 UTC] {cloud_sql.py:630} INFO - 2023/08/23
> 22:01:55 Listening on 127.0.0.1:44687 for
> my_gcp_project_id:northamerica-northeast1:test
>
> [2023-08-23, 22:01:55 UTC] {cloud_sql.py:630} INFO - 2023/08/23
> 22:01:55 Ready for new connections
>
> [2023-08-23, 22:01:55 UTC] {cloud_sql.py:1217} INFO - Executing:
> "TRUNCATE TABLE mytable" [2023-08-23, 22:04:05 UTC] {cloud_sql.py:646}
> INFO - Stopping the cloud_sql_proxy pid: 9951 [2023-08-23, 22:04:05
> UTC] {cloud_sql.py:650} INFO - Removing the socket directory:
> /tmp/dqnjbnio [2023-08-23, 22:04:05 UTC] {cloud_sql.py:653} INFO -
> Removing downloaded proxy: /tmp/dqnjbnio_cloud_sql_proxy [2023-08-23,
> 22:04:05 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1778} ERROR - Task failed with
> exception Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/cloud_sql.py",
> line 1236, in execute
> self._execute_query(hook, database_hook)   File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/cloud_sql.py",
> line 1218, in _execute_query
> database_hook.run(self.sql, self.autocommit, parameters=self.parameters)   File
> "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/common/sql/hooks/sql.py",
> line 385, in run
> with closing(self.get_conn()) as conn:   File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/postgres/hooks/postgres.py",
> line 154, in get_conn
> self.conn = psycopg2.connect(**conn_args)   File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py",
> line 122, in connect
> conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync) psycopg2.OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly   This probably means the server terminated abnormally
> before or while processing the request.
>
> [2023-08-23, 22:04:05 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1328} INFO - Marking task
> as FAILED. dag_id=from_gcs_to_cloudsql,
> task_id=delete_older_data_task, execution_date=20230823T215359,
> start_date=20230823T220146, end_date=20230823T220405 [2023-08-23,
> 22:04:05 UTC] {warnings.py:109} WARNING -
> /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/sendgrid/utils/emailer.py:123:
> AirflowProviderDeprecationWarning: Fetching Sendgrid credentials from
> environment variables will be deprecated in a future release. Please
> set credentials using a connection instead.
> _post_sendgrid_mail(mail.get(), conn_id)
>
> [2023-08-23, 22:04:05 UTC] {emailer.py:145} INFO - Email with subject
> Airflow alert: <TaskInstance:
> from_gcs_to_cloudsql.delete_older_data_task
> manual__2023-08-23T21:53:59.693259+00:00 [failed]> is successfully
> sent to recipients: [{'to': [{'email': 'my_email@test.com'}]}]
> [2023-08-23, 22:04:05 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:100} ERROR -
> Failed to execute job 69591 for task delete_older_data_task (server
> closed the connection unexpectedly    This probably means the server
> terminated abnormally     before or while processing the request. ; 9949)
> [2023-08-23, 22:04:05 UTC] {local_task_job.py:212} INFO - Task exited
> with return code 1 [2023-08-23, 22:04:05 UTC] {taskinstance.py:2599}
> INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check

Comment: Do you use Cloud Composer 2? Do you have a public IP on your database or only a private one?

Comment: Yes, I am using Cloud Composer. That Cloud SQL PostgreSQL database doesn't have public IP. I can use Cloud SQL Proxy to access it and submit queries.

Comment: But is it the version 1 or the version 2 of Cloud Composer?

Comment: The composer version is 2.4.1.  Airflow version is 2.5.3. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's a network flaws and it's a bit complex. Let me explain.

When you run your Cloud SQL, it's a managed service, that means the instance is not in your VPC, it's in a Google VPC/project. To use it in your VPC, you have to perform a VPC peering.

When you use GKE Autopilot, it's a managed service, that means the instances (the nodes of the node pools) are not in your VPC, it's a a google VPC/Project. To use it in your VPC, you have to perform a VPC peeing.

The problem comes now: With Google Cloud there is no transitivity in the Network peering. That means:

- If your GKE autopilot access your VPC
- And if your VPC access your Cloud SQL instance
- Your GKE Autopilot **CAN'T** access your Cloud SQL instance (no transitivity).

---

That's being said, you have 3 solutions to solve it.

- The worse one: Use 1 VPC to peer GKE autopilot, and use another VPC to peer Cloud SQL. Then create a VPN (not a peering) between the VPCs
- You can use a solution similar to [datafusion use case (same situation) with a VM proxy](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/connect-to-cloud-sql-source)
- My preferred ones: You can use a preview feature named [Private Service Connect (PSC) for Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/private-service-connect-with-managed-databases). You create a Load Balancer in your VPC that abstract the access to the Cloud SQL. Then, your GKE autopilot use the Load Balancer IP instead of the database IP. The magic of PSC is the abstraction of the network part, and it works great!